# Aukey Network Adapter Won't Work In Linux

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, mint

I have an [Aukey network adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01B7I19MQ) that says it will only work with Windows. But I have read that there are possible ways to get it working on Linux but none of them worked.

Can any of you guys help me get it working? (I am going to use Linux Mint 18 Sarah but I am testing it with a live image of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Results Of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e8d:7610 MediaTek Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0781:5575 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 0566:3107 Monterey International Corp. Keyboard
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:0809 Logitech, Inc. Webcam Pro 9000
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c531 Logitech, Inc. C-U0007 [Unifying Receiver]
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c07c Logitech, Inc. M-R0017 [G700s Rechargeable Gaming Mouse]
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please insert the device and run the terminal command: `lsusb` Next, edit your question to add the result. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: In addition to chili555's comment please try a more recent version of Ubuntu.

Comment: My pc won't support the latest one because it kernel panics.

Comment: But i can try to run it

Comment: Edited It. Now you can see it LiveWireBT (Used Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Live image (It works))

Answer (score 1):

I have the same Adapter; the AUKEY WF-R3.

My almost-working solution is to make and install the patched driver by *xtknight*: https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes

1. Get the .zip (from the green *Clone or download* button at the link) somehow onto the connection-less device.
2. Extract the files onto the desktop.
3. Open the resulting folder, right click and choose *Open in Terminal*
4. Type `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.
5. Type `make clean`.
6. Then type, `make`.
7. If that finished without errors, then the last step should be to type `sudo make install`.

That *should work*. For me, nothing showed up in the network manager. Here's [an issue that I've opened for that reason](https://github.com/xtknight/mt7610u-linksys-ae6000-wifi-fixes/issues/18); hopefully it will be resolved soon.

Comment: You can use command substitution there `linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Thanks @Zanna! That makes things much simpler—I had an inkling that could be done easier.